# How to resolve UmbrellaException error in java using phantomjs and selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, gwt, phantomjs

I want to test login to a page automatically using selenium and phantomJs this is my code it's work fine with firefox but i need to use phantomJs

```
try {
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, "D:\\phantomjs_2_1_1\\bin\\phantomjs.exe");
        caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_PAGE_SETTINGS_PREFIX,"Y");
        caps.setCapability("phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:16.0) Gecko/20121026 Firefox/16.0");
        caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
        caps.setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);

        PhantomJSDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);

        driver.get("mypage-login");

        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);

        File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);


        FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("d:\\sample.png"),true);

        System.out.println("FIND ELEMENT [OK] ");


        new WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(
                ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"elemId17\"]"))).click();

        scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

        System.out.println("scrFile := " + scrFile.getAbsolutePath());
        FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("d:\\sample2.png"),true);

        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"x-auto-1-input\"]")).sendKeys("username");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"x-auto-5-input\"]")).sendKeys("domain");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"x-auto-4-input\"]")).sendKeys("password");

        new WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(
                ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"elemId98\"]"))).click();

        scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("d:\\sample3.png"),true);

        if (driver.findElement(By.id("elemId98")) == null)
            System.out.println("OK");
        System.out.println("KO");


    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        System.out.println("life is good !");
    }
```

The errors that a got is :

```
ERROR - 2018-04-24T16:23:41.092Z] Session [cb29bc00-47db-11e8-9aae-df14adbccf9e] - page.onError - msg: Error: com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: Exception caught: (TypeError) : null is not an object (evaluating 'result[1]')
phantomjs://platform/console++.js:263 in error
[ERROR - 2018-04-24T16:23:41.092Z] Session [cb29bc00-47db-11e8-9aae-df14adbccf9e] - page.onError - stack: vkb (mypage:326)
 dispatchEvent (:0)
U (:119) $ (:108)
$ (:101)
gh (:141)
sh (:152)
(anonymous function) (:152)
(anonymous function) (:152)
(anonymous function) (:153)
phantomjs://platform/console++.js:263 in error
```

In the screenshot i can see something that's not ok; after the last test (this code below) i add a new TakesScreenshot after a sleep for 10s the result was the same like before in the screenshot number 3 'simple3' it seem like it's blocked in this phase ( login button clicked and an animation for loading index or error page was shown)

```
 if (driver.findElement(By.id("elemId98")) == null)
            System.out.println("OK");
        System.out.println("KO");
```

any addition information i'm listening and thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

### UmbrellaException

[**UmbrellaException**](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/web/bindery/event/shared/UmbrellaException.html) is the Java *RuntimeException* defined in **com.google.web.bindery.event.shared** package of [**gwtproject**](http://www.gwtproject.org/) that collects a set of child Throwables together. This exception is typically thrown after a loop, with all of the exceptions thrown during that loop, but delayed so that the loop finishes executing.

A detailed error stack trace would have helped us to research the issue in a better way. But as per the following discussions :

- [UmbrellaException when button is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10172987/umbrellaexception-when-button-is-clicked)
- [GWT/JAVA Uncaught exception escaped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343483/gwt-java-uncaught-exception-escaped)

It seems the root cause of **com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException** is **java.lang.NullPointerException**

### The problems and the solution

You need to take care of a certain things in your code as follows :

- When the element identified as `(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"elemId98\"]"))` is returned as you are trying to invoke `click()` instead of *ExpectedConditions* method `presenceOfElementLocated()` you must use [**`elementToBeClickable()`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable-org.openqa.selenium.By-) as follows :

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='elemId98']"))).click();
  ```

  This should be a part of practice while waiting for any element to be clickable.
- If the elelemt identified as `(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"elemId98\"]"))` is returned after *WebDriverWait* and `click()` is invoked thereafter in the next step `findElement()` won't be able to find the previous element again as in :

  ```
  if (driver.findElement(By.id("elemId98")) == null)
  ```

  Here possibly a [**NoSuchElementException**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/NoSuchElementException.html) or  [**StaleElementReferenceException**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/StaleElementReferenceException.html) should have been raised.
- Next as you have tried to compare the result of `driver.findElement(By.id("elemId98"))` with **null** which is not as per the best practices. As per the documentation of [**`findElement()`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-) it is clearly mentioned that :

> [**`findElement()`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-) should not be used to look for non-present elements, use [**`findElements(By)`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElements-org.openqa.selenium.By-) and assert zero length response instead.

### Conclusion

All these issues/error are happening within the `**try-catch {}**` block which combinedly throws **com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException**. Abiding by the mentioned steps will solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks [https://stackoverflow.com/users/7429447/debanjanb] DebanjanB for your replay  but the problem still existing i add ```System.exit(-2); ``` after 
```new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='elemId98']"))).click();```

the error exist ! what mean that the problem is with this click becouse before it when i add a System exit all is fine

Comment: @Mks Let us debug the issue, pull out the line outside _try{}_ block and validate what `new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='elemId98']")))` returns. If it _timesout_ the problem is with the _xpath_. In that case update the question with the relevant _HTML_

Comment: i'd the following : 

```WebElement obj = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='elemId98']")));
        System.out.println("OBJ Click := " + obj.getText());```

Comment: So what was the output?

Comment: ```System.out.println("OBJ Click := " + obj.getText());``` to this point it's ok the output was : Login (the text in the button) but when i add  obj.click(); the error comeback

Comment: This is because of your excessive exception handling blocks. The steps you have tried shouldn't have raised any exception. Remove the `try-catch{}` and execute your steps. raise a new question with the errors you face stackoverflow volunteers will help you out for sure.

Comment: I remove the try{} block but still the same problem i came with an other probably source of this error ; maybe the dependencies version is not compatible org.seleniumhq.selenium 2.53.1 com.codeborne : 1.4.4 org.seleniumhq.selenium : 3.4.0 com.google.guava : 22.0 org.apache.commons 1.3.2

Comment: Update _Selenium_ to **v3.11.0** and execute your tests.

Comment: the same problem ;( hh